# Find text no longer working in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Ctrl-F (and the equivalent menu option) no longer works in Visual Studio 2019 Preview 3 this morning. It was working fine yesterday, but after I turned my machine on this morning it doesn't do anything. An upgrade to preview 4 doesn't fix this issue.

The font sizes are also a little screwed up - they seem to default to a bigger font each time I reboot VS.

I think this could be a corrupt config issue, but have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: You are doing beta testing but expect production quality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

> Alt + W + R

this will ask you a pop up for restoring to default select 'Yes'.

[image]

OR

Select **Window** -> **Reset Window Layout**

relaunch the VS and validate it.

Comment: Thanks - I actually reinstalled VS which worked, but did seem like a bit of overkill. I'll try this if it happens again.